# Run Windows service by installutil and facing permission issue c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

i developed a small windows service where sql dependency classes to monitor table changes. if table change occur then service call a web service. this service create a folder and file to save the log and also service send mail to user.

i try to copy service exe file in a folder of program files folder and issue this command `installutil  C:\BBA-Reman\PartIndexer\MyService.exe`

getting error related message and i understood that permission is getting a issue. so i open the command prompt as **run as admin** and then i was my service is running fine and also could create folder & file for saving log data.

so what i did now. i add a Manifest.xml file in my project and make a association that file with my project. Manifest.xml file content here.

this area i change in manifest file for running my service with admin privilege

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

i again compile my service and just open command prompt without run as admin and issue the same command `installutil  C:\BBA-Reman\PartIndexer\PartIndexerService.exe` getting the same permission issue related error message as before.

so please guide me how could i run my service with admin privilege by manifest file. what i am doing wrong for which i am getting error even after adding manifest file. looking for suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use Topshelf in your C# application, it eases the process of windows services installation.

Here you can find more details about it:
http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html

Comment: i have no knowledge about what is topshelf. if we run my exe by topshelf then does it run as win service? does my service name will be shown in services windows from where i can start and stop service. what is the advantage of running any exe as win service by topshelf ? please share the knowledge. thanks

Comment: It is easy to install via nuget gallery. Simple, few liner makes from your console app a windows service. It is far easier to debug a console application than a service. And once the application is tested and ready for production, Topshelf makes it easy to install the application as a service. If you have never tried it, It is really worth to try now when you have a problem with that. You can find more info about topshelf on their FAQ page: http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/faq.html